# Why regret is used in online machine learning and is there any intuitive explanation about it?

Tags: machine-learning, online-algorithms

Why regret is used in online machine learning?

Is there any intuitive explanation about it?

Are there any other measurements to be optimized except the regret in online learning?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Regret" as a term that applies to online machine learning is one that lends itself very easily to an intuitive explanation.

Minimizing (or, alternatively, optimizing for) "regret" is simply reducing the number of actions taken which, in hindsight, it is apparent that there was a better choice. By minimizing regret, we are minimizing subobtimal actions by the algorithm.

Depending on the application of the online machine learning algorithm, there can be many, many other measurements to be optimized.

Several specific papers you may be interested discuss the topic in depth:

[Learning, Regret minimization, and Equilibria](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/Papers/regret-chapter.pdf) - *A. Blum and Y. Mansour*

[Optimization for Machine Learning](http://ie.technion.ac.il/~ehazan/papers/opt_book.pdf) - *Hazan*

[Online Learning and Online
Convex Optimization](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/papers/OLsurvey.pdf) - *Shalev-Shwartz*

Comment: Can regret be negative?

Comment: No- you cannot do better than the best you can do.

Comment: What about in the case of randomized weighted majority algorithm?

Comment: In that case, I think what you're referring to is a *mistake* by one of the *experts* in the algorithm. Regret as a measure could be applied in at least two ways here: first, as a measure of the effectiveness of a single expert's predictions (with an appropriate cost function). That would give you a regret score- how much value the actions driven by an expert's predictions lose relative to the *best possible outcome*. Notably- this is equivalent to the backward-looking best possible outcome, not the forward-looking *best outcome that possibly could have been predicted beforehand*.

Comment: You could also apply that same scheme to the algorithm overall.

Comment: Regret is most often used as a metric that informs the training of reinforcement learning algorithms- if the *experts* were RL algorithms (or people genuinely interested in that form of feedback, I suppose) they could use the regret of their predictions to learn a new policy of producing predictions.

Comment: @AdityaDas yes, regret can be negative. Regret is (algorithm's loss) - (loss of optimal fixed action). Because the algorithm does not have to stick to a single fixed action, it could perform better than the benchmark.